# DocuSign SignHere Location

Tags: location, docusignapi, signature

I'm having some trouble getting the signature tag to show on the correct location.

I have 2 separate signers with one document to sign. Each signer must sign one unique signature with separate label names.

```
    private SignHere buildSignHere(Signature signature, String documentId) {

        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setTabLabel(getSignatureLabel(signature));
        signHere.setPageNumber(String.valueOf(signature.getSignatureLocationId().getPage().intValue() + 1));
        signHere.setDocumentId(documentId);

        return signHere;
    }
```

I then simply create a Tabs and add the SignHere to the Tabs. Each signer has their own Tabs object. What ends up happening is that the signature location is at the top of the page, but in the original PDF, the signature location is defined in a different area.

So my question is - why does DocuSign not pick up the correct location based on the label name identified? Is there a way to configure this so that it automatically picks up the location from the label? The length/width and X/Y coordinates are already defined by the label within the PDF, so I'm confused as to why it doesn't pick that up, or does it need to be explicitly provided? I'm looking for a solution to pick up the coordinates automatically.

Please note, I have also tried turning on setTransformPdfFields("true") for the Document object. While this method does pick up the correct location, it does not produce the result I need because it allows both signature locations to be visible for both signers, which is incorrect. I need each signer to only see their own signature as identified in the SignHere object. So it seems there is a way to pick up the location automatically via the setTransformPdfFields(), but not by using the setTabLabel() within the SignHere object.

Here is the full json for the request I made.

```
{
   "attachments":[

   ],
   "compositeTemplates":[

   ],
   "documents":[
      {
         "documentBase64":"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",
         "documentFields":[

         ],
         "documentId":"1",
         "fileExtension":"pdf",
         "matchBoxes":[

         ],
         "name":"8943520714564164772_1597681120885.pdf",
         "pageSizes":[

         ]
      }
   ],
   "emailSubject":"Nazir Noori has added you as a Signer.",
   "envelopeAttachments":[

   ],
   "envelopeDocuments":[

   ],
   "eventNotifications":[

   ],
   "folders":[

   ],
   "recipients":{
      "agents":[

      ],
      "carbonCopies":[

      ],
      "certifiedDeliveries":[

      ],
      "editors":[

      ],
      "inPersonSigners":[

      ],
      "intermediaries":[

      ],
      "seals":[

      ],
      "signers":[
         {
            "customFields":[

            ],
            "documentVisibility":[

            ],
            "email":"nazir.noori44@gmail.com",
            "excludedDocuments":[

            ],
            "firstName":"Nazir",
            "lastName":"Noori",
            "name":"Nazir Noori",
            "recipientAttachments":[

            ],
            "recipientFeatureMetadata":[

            ],
            "recipientId":"1",
            "recipientSignatureProviders":[

            ],
            "roleName":"signer",
            "routingOrder":"1",
            "signingGroupUsers":[

            ],
            "socialAuthentications":[

            ],
            "tabs":{
               "approveTabs":[

               ],
               "checkboxTabs":[

               ],
               "commentThreadTabs":[

               ],
               "companyTabs":[

               ],
               "dateSignedTabs":[

               ],
               "dateTabs":[

               ],
               "declineTabs":[

               ],
               "emailAddressTabs":[

               ],
               "emailTabs":[

               ],
               "envelopeIdTabs":[

               ],
               "firstNameTabs":[

               ],
               "formulaTabs":[

               ],
               "fullNameTabs":[

               ],
               "initialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "lastNameTabs":[

               ],
               "listTabs":[

               ],
               "notarizeTabs":[

               ],
               "noteTabs":[

               ],
               "numberTabs":[

               ],
               "polyLineOverlayTabs":[

               ],
               "radioGroupTabs":[

               ],
               "signerAttachmentTabs":[

               ],
               "signHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":"2",
                     "tabGroupLabels":[

                     ],
                     "tabLabel":"_.signaturePanel[SIGNATURE][1].signatory[ADVISOR][1]"
                  }
               ],
               "smartSectionTabs":[

               ],
               "ssnTabs":[

               ],
               "tabGroups":[

               ],
               "textTabs":[

               ],
               "titleTabs":[

               ],
               "viewTabs":[

               ],
               "zipTabs":[

               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "customFields":[

            ],
            "documentVisibility":[

            ],
            "email":"nathan.sypes44@gmail.com",
            "excludedDocuments":[

            ],
            "firstName":"Nathan",
            "idCheckConfigurationName":"SMS Auth $",
            "lastName":"Sypes",
            "name":"Nathan Sypes",
            "recipientAttachments":[

            ],
            "recipientFeatureMetadata":[

            ],
            "recipientId":"2",
            "recipientSignatureProviders":[

            ],
            "roleName":"signer",
            "routingOrder":"2",
            "signingGroupUsers":[

            ],
            "smsAuthentication":{
               "senderProvidedNumbers":[
                  "4168564209"
               ]
            },
            "socialAuthentications":[

            ],
            "tabs":{
               "approveTabs":[

               ],
               "checkboxTabs":[

               ],
               "commentThreadTabs":[

               ],
               "companyTabs":[

               ],
               "dateSignedTabs":[

               ],
               "dateTabs":[

               ],
               "declineTabs":[

               ],
               "emailAddressTabs":[

               ],
               "emailTabs":[

               ],
               "envelopeIdTabs":[

               ],
               "firstNameTabs":[

               ],
               "formulaTabs":[

               ],
               "fullNameTabs":[

               ],
               "initialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "lastNameTabs":[

               ],
               "listTabs":[

               ],
               "notarizeTabs":[

               ],
               "noteTabs":[

               ],
               "numberTabs":[

               ],
               "polyLineOverlayTabs":[

               ],
               "radioGroupTabs":[

               ],
               "signerAttachmentTabs":[

               ],
               "signHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "documentId":"1",
                     "pageNumber":"2",
                     "tabGroupLabels":[

                     ],
                     "tabLabel":"_.signaturePanel[SIGNATURE][1].signatory[INVESTOR][1]"
                  }
               ],
               "smartSectionTabs":[

               ],
               "ssnTabs":[

               ],
               "tabGroups":[

               ],
               "textTabs":[

               ],
               "titleTabs":[

               ],
               "viewTabs":[

               ],
               "zipTabs":[

               ]
            }
         }
      ],
      "witnesses":[

      ]
   },
   "status":"sent",
   "templateRoles":[

   ]
}
```

Would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding for example "xPosition": "100","yPosition":"100" to signHereTabs
as per this guide https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs

Comment: Looks like our software was actually passing the wrong coordinates. Thanks for the suggestion.